# Nagios::Object::Config it is behaving unexpectedly

Tags: perl, nagios

I am by no means an expert in Perl but I am trying to debug a script nagios_reader_to_centreon_clapi.pl from https://github.com/centreon/nagiosToCentreon/blob/master/nagios_reader_to_centreon_clapi.pl it is behaving unexpectedly on line 656 giving output like

```
SERVICE;setcontactgroup;server.example.com;mailbox_status_node1;Nagios::ContactGroup=HASH(0xe28550)|Nagios::ContactGroup=HASH(0xe2ae10)
```

I have stripped down the code to the bare minimum in order to reproduce the expected results and the unexpected results.

test.pl

```
use Nagios::Config;
use Nagios::Object::Config;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';
use Getopt::Long;

Getopt::Long::Configure('bundling');
GetOptions(
    "C|config=s"    => \$OPTION{'config'}
);

my $objects;
$objects = Nagios::Config->new( Filename => $OPTION{'config'} );
my @services_array = $objects->list_services();
foreach my $service ( @services_array ){
        foreach my $item ( @{$service->contact_groups} ) {
            $var = ref $item;
            print "$var \n";
            say Dumper($item);
        }
}
```

test.cfg

```
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/new-hosts.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/new-services.cfg
cfg_file=/etc/nagios/new-contactgroups.cfg
```

new-hosts.cfg

```
define host{
        host_name                       server1.example.com
#       use                             generic_ht
        alias                           Server 01
        address                         xxx.xx.xxx.xxx
        hostgroups                      servers
        active_checks_enabled           1
        contact_groups                  Group3
}
```

new-services.cfg

```
define service{
        name                            generic_st
        service_description             generic_st
        max_check_attempts              3
        normal_check_interval           5
        retry_check_interval            1
        active_checks_enabled           1
        passive_checks_enabled          1
        check_period                    24x7
        notification_interval           240
        notification_period             24x7
        notification_options            w,c,r
        notifications_enabled           1
        contact_groups                  Group1
        register                        0
}

define service{
        host_name                       server1.example.com
        service_description             service1
        use                             generic_st
        check_command                   check_cmd!10000!12000
        contact_groups                  Group2
}

define service{
        name                        service2
        service_description         service02
        use                         generic_st
        check_command               check_cmd2
        active_checks_enabled       1
        passive_checks_enabled      1
        check_period                24x7
        notifications_enabled       1
        contact_groups              Group4, Group3
        register                    0
}
```

new-contactgroups.cfg

```
define contactgroup{
        contactgroup_name               Group1 
        alias                           Group1
        members                         Member1
}
define contactgroup{
        contactgroup_name               Group2
        alias                           Group2
        members                         Member2
}

define contactgroup{
        contactgroup_name               Group3
        alias                           Group3
        members                         Member3
}

define contactgroup{
        contactgroup_name               Group4
        alias                           Group04
        members                         MMember4
}
```

running the script the output starts:

```
 perl test.pl   --config /etc/nagios/test.cfg
Nagios::ContactGroup
$VAR1 = bless( {
             'object_config_object' => bless( {
                                                'hostdependency_list' => [],
                                                'host_index' => {
                                                                     'server1.example.com' => [
                                                                                             bless( {
                                                                                                      'flap_detection_enabled' => undef,
                                                                                                      'check_freshness' => undef,
                                                                                                      'failure_prediction_enabled' => undef,
                                                                                                      'file' => undef,
                                                                                                      'check_period' => undef,
                                                                                                      'initial_state' => undef,
                                                                                                      'freshness_threshold' => undef,
                                                                                                      'notes_url' => undef,
                                                                                                      'first_notification_delay' => undef,
```

and ends with:

```
 'alias' => 'Group2',
             '_has_been_resolved' => 1
           }, 'Nagios::ContactGroup' );


$VAR1 = 'Group4';


$VAR1 = 'Group3';
```

The last two lines are as expected but the first part does not work with the script I am trying to debug. Has anyone got any suggestions as to how I can get the desired strings from the object I am getting or else another way to handle it?

Comment: try: `print $item->name . "\n";`

Comment: It gives: Group2
Can't locate object method "name" via package "Group4" (perhaps you forgot to load "Group4"?) at test.pl line 20.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks stevieb you put me on the right path. This seems to work:

```
use Nagios::Config;
use Nagios::Object::Config;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';
use Getopt::Long;

Getopt::Long::Configure('bundling');
GetOptions(
    "C|config=s"    => \$OPTION{'config'}
);

my $objects;
$objects = Nagios::Config->new( Filename => $OPTION{'config'} );
my @services_array = $objects->list_services();
foreach my $service ( @services_array ){
    foreach my $item ( @{$service->contact_groups} ) {
        $var = ref $item;
        if ($var eq "Nagios::ContactGroup"){
            print $item->name . "\n";
         } else {
             print $item . "\n";
         }
    }
}
```

In the original file:

```
if ( scalar @{$host->contact_groups} > 1 ) {
    foreach my $item ( @{$host->contact_groups} ) {
        $item_type = ref $item;
        if ($item_type eq "Nagios::ContactGroup"){
            $contactgroups_list .= sprintf ( "%s", $item->name) . "|";
        } else {
            $contactgroups_list .= sprintf ( "%s", $item) . "|";
        }   
    }
```

and

```
if ( scalar @{$service->contact_groups} > 1 ) {
    foreach my $item ( @{$service->contact_groups} ) {
         $item_type = ref $item;
         if ($item_type eq "Nagios::ContactGroup"){
             $contactgroups_list .= sprintf ( "%s", $item->name) . "|";
         } else {
             $contactgroups_list .= sprintf ( "%s", $item) . "|";
         }
    }
```